# IntelliJ cant locate the 'src' folder from a cloned project in Github.

Tags: github, intellij-idea

I cloned a project in Github which specifically an IntelliJ java project , this project contains java source code, Everything is downloaded including the 'src' , 'iml', README and '.idea' (I already double checked it and yes everything is downloaded correctly). However the moment I open the project project it seems that  I cant find the src, here is what it looks like :

[image]

As you can see in above image 'SRC' folder seems missing although it is downloaded, What are the things I missed up in this cloning? and how can I fixed it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the Algorithm.iml file is not added as a module to the project. There is an option to add it to the project in the context menu if you right-click on the .iml file.